# Where is this final number coming from?

Tags: javascript

If I run the following code in Chrome console (apologies for the label):

```
var x = 0;

theLoop:
    while (1) {

        if (!(x <= 2)) {
            break theLoop;
        }

        console.log('x: ', x);
        ++x;
        continue theLoop;
    }
```

The following is output to the console:

```
x:  0
x:  1
x:  2
3
```

It's late, so I'm missing something very obvious, but where is the '3' coming from?

Comment: Works fine http://jsfiddle.net/bfvzbcmL/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't worry about that: it is not an actual console.log, but just your browser that displays the last value that has been read (unless it is assigned to a `var`), in this case the `++x` that equals 3.

For instance if at the end of your snippet you add `console.log('the end');` or even just `0;` the last log will be different, yet won't affect your program.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Chrome by default prints the last assigned variable, but only when it was assigned at least twice, so this:

```js
   
var x = 5;
var y = 3;
```

will result with nothing, but

```js
var x = 5;
x = 4;
var y = 3;
```

will give you `4`.

In your case it was `x=3`

Comment: What is an assumed variable?

Comment: It meant to be assigned variable. It's really late, time to go sleep:)

Comment: It doesn't matter how many times you assign it, Chrome will display the last expression unless it is put into a `var`. test your exemple with only the line `x = 4` and you will see 4.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen such too. But the value is not used in application. Firefox won't display it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so `3` is the console returning value of `x` after the loop, the reason `x == 3` is that after the line `x: 2` is displayed|logged `++x` once again increments `x`, ergo `x == 3`!